# some issue about thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

A thread class:

```
class NewThread extends thread{
    public void abc(){
    }
}
```

then in another thread's a method perform these code

```
public void buttonClicked(){
   NewThread  thread = new NewThread();
   thread.start();
   thread.abc();
}
```

1. OK,so the object `thread`'s life cycle is up to the method `buttonClicked`, so if the method return, object `thread` will be destroy even if `thread.start()` is still running?
2. Assume `buttonClicked()` is invoked when we click a button. So I click the button several times, every time I click it, a new Object `thread` will be created,in this case, there are many different "NewThread" Object exist in JVM? I do like this, then JVM crash,In my PC,it appears that my java program lose answering,I must use task manager to kill java.exe,but sometimes it's ok,weird!!
3. In `buttonClicked()` method ,before invoke `thread.abc();` if `thread.start()` is already finished,can i still invoke the thread object`thread.abc();`?

Comment: I think that the thread object is not destroyed, you just can't reference to it in code, but is does exist somewhere in the JVM, what crash do you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Thread Garbage collected or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423284/java-thread-garbage-collected-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

> OK, so the object "thread"'s life cycle is up to the method `buttonClicked`, so if the method return, object thread will be destroy even if `thread.start()` is still running?

I see two missunderstandings here:

- If the method `buttonClicked` returns, the *reference to the object* will be gone. The object instance of `NewThread` will be still alive until no one references it and additionally a garbage collector decides to reclaim that memory. This means, that the instance of `NewThread` will be there at least as long as the `run()` method of `NewThread` is running because the stack of the thread which is described by the `NewThread` instance references that instance. That stack will be cleared when `run()` terminates.
- `thread.start()` will return immediately. It only signals the second thread to start working.

> Assume buttonClicked() will be invoke when we click a button, so I click the button several times, every time I click it, a new Object thread will be created, so in this case, there are many different "NewThread" Object exist in JVM?

In fact you are accumulating `NewThread` instances if the `run()` method of `NewThread` is slow compared to your click rate.

> I do like this, then JVM crash.

You mean you like clicking buttons and the following JVM crash? ;-)

**Edit:** After the question has been changed/extended, a third point appeared:

> In `buttonClicked()` method, before invoke `thread.abc();` if `thread.start()` is already finished, can i still invoke the thread object `thread.abc();`?

Of course you can invoke any method on an object as long as you have a reference. `Thread` is no exception here.

I think the main difficulty you have is this: The reference `thread` points to an object. This object is *not* the real thread (note the small *t*), it is only some small memory area with some descriptions about the real thread. The real thread consists of some CPU settings, the OS scheduler stuff, a stack and so on.

The lifetimes of these two *things*, the object and the real thread, are not coupled strictly: The object `Thread` exists before the real thread is created (which happens inside `Thread.start()` ). The real thread dies after leaving the `run()` method. But the *object* `Thread` exists even after that up to the point when normal garbage collection kicks in as already described.

Answer (score 0):

Thread is not destroyed after exiting from method. Reference to thread is saved in "thread table" which is accessible by static link (so thread won't garbage collected).

Answer (score 0):

A Thread is also known to be the garbage root and this it is not cleaned up by the garbage collector. GC decides if an object is reachable or not by  using the set of garbage collector root as reference points.  This is also the reason why the main thread doesn't get collected by the garbage collector.

> An object enters an unreachable state when no more strong references
>   to it exist. When an object is unreachable, it is a candidate for
>   collection. Note the wording: Just because an object is a candidate
>   for collection doesn't mean it will be immediately collected. The JVM
>   is free to delay collection until there is an immediate need for the
>   memory being consumed by the object. It's important to note that not
>   just any strong reference will hold an object in memory. These must be
>   references that chain from a garbage collection root. GC roots are a
>   special class of variable that includes
>
> Temporary variables on the stack (of any thread) Static variables
>   (from any class) Special references from JNI native code

Taken from : http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html#997428