# When this new Thread() is GC'ed in Android?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, dalvik

I'm having a util class where I'm trying to write to secure setting like,

```
public static void putIntInSS(final ContentResolver resolver, final String key,
                                                    final int value) {
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 Settings.Secure.putInt(resolver, key, value);
             }
         }).start();
}
```

When this `new Thread()` would be GC'ed? Is it good to use `new Thread()` in my application instead of `Handler`? If there is some disadvantage of using threads in this way what are they?

Comment: Just curious, what motivated you to put this operation in a thread in the first place?

Comment: Just thinking that write to secure setting might increase delay and might block the ui thread..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread will become a candidate for GC just as soon as it finishes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423290/6759241).

**"Is it good to use new Thread() in my application instead of Handler?"**

In a word, "no". You should make sure you understand all the pros & cons of multithreading, and proper concurrency techniques, before you start putting extra threads in production code. It's hard to overstate the elegance of a message-based queueing system (e.g., `Handler`), especially for message-driven UI based apps (Android, Windows). A `Handler` is an effective way of creating the illusion of concurrency, even if it is limited to the throughput of a single thread.

**"some disadvantage of using threads in this way..."**

Well, there are a lot. I'll go ahead and get the list started:

- There is no guarantee that operations conducted in this way will execute in any particular order.
- There is no guarantee that the operation will begin in a timely manner.
- The operation might actually end up executing more slowly, due to the overhead associated with creating/scheduling the thread, and [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

The above mentioned problems will become acute if you start many operations like this in a short time span. Furthermore:

- You can never know if (or when) an operation has finished. (That takes additional code.) In particular, when using the objects passed to the "outer" method, you cannot be sure that the thread is done using them by the time the "outer" method returns.
- The technique increases code complexity; you can see how verbose it is.
- Any operation that you put on another thread must have the appropriate attention given to concurrency. You must make sure the methods that you call are threadsafe, if there is any possibility of concurrent access. Detailed synchronization efforts may be needed.
- Error handling becomes complex.

A lot of software engineering is about how to avoid unnecessary complexity. Keep things simple. Sometimes you're gonna have demanding performance requirements; those projects require careful planning and a detailed understanding of how a CPU works. Most of the time, the most important thing about a piece of software is that it's *correct*. And for that, it's easier to stay single-threaded.