# Can't get past 2542 Threads in Java on 4GB iMac OSX 10.6.3 Snow Leopard (32bit)

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, macos, memory

I am running the following program trying to figure out how to configure my JVM to get the maximum number of threads my machine can support. For those that might not know, Snow Leopard ships with Java 6.

I tried starting it with defaults, and the following command lines, I always get the Out of Memory Error at Thread 2542 no matter what the JVM options are set to.

```
java TestThreadStackSizes 100000
java -Xss1024 TestThreadStackSizes 100000
java -Xmx128m -Xss1024 TestThreadStackSizes 100000
java -Xmx2048m -Xss1024 TestThreadStackSizes 100000
java -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -Xss1024 TestThreadStackSizes 100000
```

no matter what I pass it, I get the same results, Out of Memory Error at 2542

```
public class TestThreadStackSizes
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            public void uncaughtException(final Thread t, final Throwable e)
            {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
        int numThreads = 1000;
        if (args.length == 1)
        {
            numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new SleeperThread(i));
                t.start();
            }
            catch (final OutOfMemoryError e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Out of Memory Error on Thread %d", i), e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class SleeperThread implements Runnable
    {
        private final int i;

        private SleeperThread(final int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.format("Thread %d about to sleep\n", this.i);
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60);
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can affect these results?

I wrote this program to figure out what a Windows Server 2003 is capable of, because I am getting these `out of memory can't create native threads` at very low numbers, like a couple of hundred. I need to see what a particular box was capable of with different `-Xss` parameters, then I run into this arbitrary limit on OSX.

Comment: WOW, how many CPUs do you have?  You can only run one thread (perhaps two) on a CPU at any one moment.  The rest just add overhead.  If you think you need this many threads, perhaps a redesign is in order.

Comment: who said I "needed" this many threads, I just wanted to know the limits and how to change them.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: If you're working on something that's very I/O-intensive, like a webserver or somesuch, you'll often have tons of threads that are idle most of the time blocked on I/O, but still take up a slot in your OS' process table. It's not necessarily a matter of how many CPUs they're using.

Comment: @AdrianPetrescu This is true, but beyond 1000 threads they start adding significant load even if they are just blocking on IO.

Comment: "You can only run one thread (perhaps two) on a CPU at any one moment. The rest just add overhead." That's not true.  At least it's not true on anything other than CPU bound tasks.  For IO bound tasks you can have several times as many threads as CPUs without any problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### 2542 seems like an arbitrary number:

I shut all programs down except the one terminal window I was running my test from and I got to `2545`, that told me it was an arbitrary limit.

To get the number of threads for OSX 10.6.3 you do:

```
> sysctl kern.num_threads
kern.num_threads: 2560
```

and

```
> sysctl kern.num_taskthreads
kern.num_taskthreads: 2560
```

The `2560` number matches up with the `2542` and `2545` because there are obviously other threads running in the background.
According to the official documentation `kern.num_taskthreads` can not be adjusted in the desktop version of OSX.

Comment: Testing 'sysctl kern.num_threads' on OS X 10.8 and 10.11 the number shows as 10240.  It would appear to have increased.

Comment: @JasonFuerstenberg Same number for me on 10.11.5 however `sysctl kern.num_taskthreads`  gives 2048 and I can't create more than 2023 threads in Java.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt jvm self also need to create threads, add 2023 will be 2048, you can jstack this process to check it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apple Developer doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/Java/JavaLeopardUpdate5RN/ResolvedIssues/ResolvedIssues.html) the thread stack size should be at least 64K, so your -Xss 1014 is ignored. But even with 64K per thread, the thread stack memory consumption comes only to about 160MB, so this shouldn't be the problem. Threads could also consume memory from a more limited pool, or there could simply be limit on the number of thread you can have per process or user.

Comment: I set it to 256k and it still fails at the exact same number of threads. java -Xss256k -XX:ThreadStackSize=256 TestThreadStackSizes 10000

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the maximum number of threads the operating system supports on your system.

On linux you can do something like :

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

to get the max, and to set it you can do something like :

```
echo 10000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

Also try running with :

```
-XX:-UseBoundThreads
```

and report back the results.

Comment: nope not on linux and -XX:-UseBoundThreads doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you will have these much thread concurrently up to 1 hour? I don't think so. I have worked in application which processed hundreds of documents, convert them from and to diff. format, generates proper logs in DB and stores specific info also. Then also it finished in seconds.

The thing you should take care about it, code wisely to avoid making too much threads. Instead use a `ThreadPool` provided by Java, so that same threads can be utilized when needed. that will provide better performance. Also keep synchronization on minimal blocks to avoid bottle necks in your execution.

thanks.