# Basic Asyncronous TCP server in Java

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a very basic asynchronous server in Java (similar to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx in C#). All of the libraries I've seen for Java are way too complex for what I need and I'm wondering if there are any libraries that are simple and have a syntax similar to the C# example.

**Edit:** Why does plain sockets require root access to listen on the loopback, but nio doesn't require root?

Comment: would be good if you can spell out the requirements rather than making us read that link of yours.

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial? : ["Writing the Server Side of a Socket"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)

Comment: Yup, but for concurrent connections, that tutorial recommends using a thread per socket... but that leads in to the link in the second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for Java's [NIO (New I/O)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) [`ServerSocketChannel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html).

Be forewarned, though: this doesn't guarantee better performance. See:

- [Java in 2011: threaded sockets VS NIO: what to choose on 64bit OS and latest Java version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437722/java-in-2011-threaded-sockets-vs-nio-what-to-choose-on-64bit-os-and-latest-java)
- http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/java-io-faster-than-nio-old-is-new-again/

Comment: Well I guess one thread per socket may just be the way to go, it seems. I'll write it using the threading then try nio to compare it.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that using a plain socket to listen to loopback requires root access, yet NIO doesn't require it... Is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

try `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel & AsynchronousSocketChannel`