# What is purpose of dispatch sync?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, synchronous, dispatch-async

I'm pretty clear what dispatch_async queue is performing, but I'm not clear what dispatch_sync purpose is. For an example: what is difference between this:

```
NSLog(@"A");
NSLog(@"B");
```

and this:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
NSLog(@"A");
    });
NSLog(@"B");
```

As I get, in both ways output will be A then B. Because sync is executed in order that is written. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the names says `dispatch_sync` makes it possible to synchronize the tasks to be executed even if they are not executed on the main queue.

[Saheb Roy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3755838/saheb-roy) answer is only half of the truth. You can only specify the dispatch queue your code should be executed on. The actual thread is chosen by GCD.

Code blocks dispatched using dispatch_async on a concurrent queue are also executed in the FIFO way and guaranteed to be executed in the order you dispatch them. The **main difference** is that dispatch_sync on a serial queue also guarantees you that following code blocks are not executed before the previous block has finished executing. `dispatch_sync` is blocking your current dispatch queue i.e. the queue your dispatch_sync call is executed on. So your calling function is blocked until the dispatched code block returns whereas `dispatch_async` returns immediately.

execution timeline using `dispatch_async` on a concurrent queue my look like this:

Block A   [..............]
Block B        [.....]
Block C           [....]

while using `dispatch_sync` on a serial queue looks like this:

Block A   [..............]
Block B                   [.....]
Block C                           [....]

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `dispatch_sync`queue is that it will dispatch blocks of code in the thread you mentioned and that the will run synchronously, meaning one by one or rather one after the other in FIFO method.
Do check out `NSOperationQueue` to understand the function of `dispatch_sync` in a better way

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_sync)

> Submits a block to a dispatch queue for synchronous execution. Unlike
>   dispatch_async, this function does not return until the block has
>   finished. Calling this function and targeting the current queue
>   results in deadlock.
>
> Unlike with dispatch_async, no retain is performed on the target
>   queue. Because calls to this function are synchronous, it "borrows"
>   the reference of the caller. Moreover, no Block_copy is performed on
>   the block.
>
> As an optimization, this function invokes the block on the current
>   thread when possible.

Answer (score -5):

Its purpose is to the multitasking. .Two or more process run at a same time  one in background thread and another in main thread. .mostly the process run in background thread and UI update in main thread to avoid screen block.

Comment: Well that's completely wrong maybe you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122842/whats-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-calls-in-objective-c