# Correct syntaxe Parse.com synchronous query - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Can someone show me an example with the correct syntax (swift please) to do a synchronous query with try/catch block. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using the synchronous `findObjects()` on `PFQuery`.

```
let query = PFQuery()
do {
    let results: [PFObject] = try query.findObjects()
    print(results)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: then I do stuff with the objects in the DO block ? like a = object.objectForKey.....

Comment: I updated the question to assign the results to an array

Comment: @Kevin Is query.findObjects() not heavily depreciated in recent Parse api installations in favour of query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(), which removes the need for try/catch handling and would make handling issues easier?

Comment: @Hyperion no, findObjects() is synchronous whereas findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() is asynchronous. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122842/whats-the-difference-between-synchronous-and-asynchronous-calls-in-objective-c