# Asynchronously running a task and returning after thread is active

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been working with threads to send a GET request to a link (all good). However, I need it to run asynchronously, so I made a new thread and ran it. Problem is I need it to return the value `returnVar[0]` after the thread is done executing. I have tried while loops with `!thread.isActive` but of course, the method body needs a return statement. I have tried `CountdownLatche`s which you are about to see, but they pause the main thread which I DON'T want. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
    public String getUUID(String username) {
    final String[] returnVar = {"ERROR"};
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {

        final String[] response = {"ERROR"};
        final JSONObject[] obj = new JSONObject[1];

        response[0] = ConnectionsManager.sendGet("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + username);

        try {
            obj[0] = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(response[0]);
            returnVar[0] = (String) obj[0].get("id");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        latch.countDown();
    });

    thread.start();


    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnVar[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using a `Callable` instead of a `Runnable`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141284/the-difference-between-the-runnable-and-callable-interfaces-in-java) for explanation and examples.

Also, it's a little strange that you are using the `CountDownLatch` with one thread. The latch is useful to make sure multiple threads are started as uniformly as possible rather than some threads getting a 'head start' in a more traditional startup.

Answer (score 0):

this is an improper use of `Thread`s.

your code runs exactly like the below code :

```
public String getUUID(String username) {
    String response = ConnectionsManager.sendGet("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + username);
    try {
        return (String) ((JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(response)).get("id");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

there are several options to make async call.

one option is to use `CompletableFuture` :

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(getUUID("username")).thenAccept(new Consumer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(String response) {
        // response of async HTTP GET
    }
});
```

learn more :

- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078809/java-concurrency/java-concurrency-java-101-the-next-generation-java-concurrency-without-the-pain-part-1.html
- http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2015/01/how-to-use-future-and-futuretask-in-Java.html
- [Difference between Future and Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541975/difference-between-future-and-promise)
- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/java-concurrency-tutorial-callable.html
- http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/
- http://www.infoq.com/articles/Functional-Style-Callbacks-Using-CompletableFuture