# How to return a value from a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a collection (`concurrentHashMap`) and a method which should work in a separate thread and return `numOfApples`:

```
public int getApples(String treeNum) {
    int numOfApples = null;
    Runnable task = () -> {concurrentHashMap.get(treeNum).getApples(); };
    new Thread(task).start() ;
    return numOfApples;
}
```

Is it possible to pass num of apples from lambda expression (`concurrentHashMap.get(treeNum).getApples()`) to the `numOfApples` variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not about returning the value from a lambda expression. It is about returning a result from an asynchronous task.

You won't be able to do that easily using a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). You should use a [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead, quoting its Javadoc:

> A task that returns a result and may throw an exception.

Also, [you definitely should not be creating unmanaged raw threads like that: `new Thread(task).start();`. You should use an `ExecutorService` and submit the `Callable` to it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18496948/1743880).

Consider the following code:

```
public int getApples(String treeNum) {
    Callable<Integer> task = () -> concurrentHashMap.get(treeNum).getApples();
    Future<Integer> future = Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit(task);
    return future.get();
}
```

It creates a `Callable<Integer>` holding the task returning the number of apples. This task is submitted to an `ExecutorService` (I simply used a cached thread pool here, you might want another). The result is contained inside a `Future<Integer>` instance, whose `get()` method will block, wait for the result and then return it.

Comment: But if the OP insist on it, it’s possible to create a [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) by hand, pass it to a new manually created thread, start it, and call `get` afterwards. The principle is the same as in your answer.

Comment: Tunaki, how to check that method executes in separate thread?

Comment: To check that the method executes in a separate thread, you could do something like `System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());` in the `getApples()` method and in the `Callable`. The ID values won't be the same.