# How to run multiple Runnable in Java threadpool?

Tags: multithreading

How can I execute bunch of different method or Runnable using "ExecutorService" parrally?
I think you understood what I am trying to say..
Thanks

Comment: Just go ahead and run them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the advantages of using an ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984076/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-an-executorservice)

Answer (score 0):

An application that creates an instance of Thread must provide the code that will run in that thread. There are two ways to do this:

Provide a Runnable object. The Runnable interface defines a single method, run, meant to contain the code executed in the thread. The Runnable object is passed to the Thread constructor, as in the HelloRunnable example:

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }

}
```

Subclass Thread. The Thread class itself implements Runnable, though its run method does nothing. An application can subclass Thread, providing its own implementation of run, as in the HelloThread example:

```
public class HelloThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new HelloThread()).start();
    }

}
```

See java documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html