# javafx textfield doesn't change

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have the following code:

```
@FXML
private void test(){
    textField.setText("Pending...");
    boolean passed = doStuff();
    if(passed){
        textField.setText("OK");
    } else {
        textField.setText("Error");
    }
}
```

And what I tries to achieve is that while the doStuff() do his stuff in a textField in the GUI there should be written "Pending..." and as soon as it finish it should change to "OK" / "Error".

I want that the GUI is blocked while doStuff is running so the user has to wait and can't click something else.

But what happens is that as soon as I start test it does the doStuff() but only updates the textField with "OK"/"Error" but I never see "Pending...".

I have the feeling that I have somehow update the GUI, but I'm not sure how it should be done.

**Update:**
What I tried is to move the doStuff in another Thread:

```
@FXML
private void test(){
    textField.setText("Pending...");
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            boolean passed = doStuff();
            if(passed){
                textField.setText("OK");
            } else {
                textField.setText("Error");
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    t.join();
}
```

It would works if i would remove the t.join(); command, but then the UI wouldn't be blocked. So I'm at a loss right now.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Task for doStuff or are you running everything in the same UI Thread?

Comment: I updated my post, yeah I tried it with and without but I'm not sure how I should do it right.

Comment: Your use of `t.join()` completely negates the use of another `Thread`. Use a `javafx.concurrent.Task` (still run it on another `Thread`) and observe it for completion. Also, when accessing live GUI objects from another thread you must wrap that code in a `Platform.runLater` call.

Comment: I don't see a difference if I use Thread or Task. Both way works but in both ways the UI isn't blocked.

Comment: You use `Task` because it provides an API for communicating back to the _JavaFX Application Thread_. If you don't need that, or you just want something simple, you can use some other `Runnable`. However, in your current example you use `Thread.join()` which _blocks the calling thread until the target thread dies_ — you might as well be running the task on the calling thread. Also see [“implements Runnable” vs “extends Thread” in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread-in-java).

Comment: Okay yeah I see this. But I'm not sure how this helps me or how I use this.
But my core problem is the following: While the doStuff is running the textfield should show the user that something is running (Textfield should show "Pending") & the GUI should be blocked. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should never block the UI thread. If you want to stop the user from interacting with your application while `doStuff` is running, then you have many other options - show a modal dialog, disable the root node, use some kind of flag that will stop user actions from executing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must never run long running tasks on the *JavaFX Application Thread*. Doing so will prevent said thread from doing any GUI related things which results in a frozen UI. This makes your user(s) sad. However, your attempt at putting the long running task on a background task is flawed. You call `Thread.join` which will block the calling thread until the target thread dies; this is effectively the same thing as just running the task on the calling thread.

For a quick fix to your example, you could do the following:

```
@FXML
private void test(){
    textField.setText("Pending...");
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        @Override public void run(){
            boolean passed = doStuff();
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                if(passed){
                    textField.setText("OK");
                } else {
                    textField.setText("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

That will create a thread, start it, and let it run in the background while letting the *JavaFX Application Thread* continue doing what it needs to. Inside the background thread you must update the `TextField` inside a `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` call. This is needed because you must *never update a live scene graph from a thread other than the JavaFX Application Thread*; doing so will lead to undefined behavior. Also, you should look into [“implements Runnable” vs “extends Thread” in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread-in-java). It's better, or at least more idiomatic, to do:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> { /* background code */ });
```

You could also use a [`javafx.concurrent.Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) which may make it easier to communicate back to the *JavaFX Application Thread*. One option would be:

```
@FXML
private void test(){
    textField.setText("Pending...");
    Task<Boolean> task = new Task<>() {
        @Override protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return doStuff();
        }
    };
    task.setOnSucceeded(event -> textField.setText(task.getValue() ? "Ok" : "Error"));
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

You could also bind the `TextField` to the `message` property of the `Task` and call `updateMessage("Pending...")` inside the `call` method. You could even provide more detailed messages if and when possible.

That said, creating and starting `Thread`s yourself is not ideal and you should look into [thread pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984076/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-an-executorservice) (using something like an `ExecutorService`). You might also want to look into [`javafx.concurrent.Service`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) for "reusing" `Task`s.

---

For more information about JavaFX concurrency see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) and read the documentation of the classes in [`javafx.concurrent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html). For the basics of multi-threading in Java see [Lesson: Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) from *The Java™ Tutorials*.