# Maximum number of threads that can run in an application?

Tags: java, multithreading, websphere

I have a java application deployed in Websphere server. I am using the thread pool in my application with size 150. apart from these, application server threads will be running. So is there a way to determine the maximum number of threads that can run in the application at any time?

EDIT:
I mean is there a way I say that the thread count at any time will not exceed some fixed number?

```
I am not creating any other thread in the application.
Using the threadpoolexecutor with size 150 to create any threads.
+application server threads.
```

So like, I can say my application can create maximum of 150 threads can I say how much an application server create at the maximum?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't a maximum, e.g. there is a GC thread per CPU by default, and threads can be started in code. Are you asking what is the largest number you should expect?

Comment: Please use google before asking. This is my first google result: http://stackoverflow.com/a/763592/6077352

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many threads can a Java VM support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763579/how-many-threads-can-a-java-vm-support)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763579/how-many-threads-can-a-java-vm-support

Comment: All, I am not asking the maximum limit of threads a JVM can have. instead I am asking, can you say at any moment how many threads can run at the maximum? can I determine the number counting on all my configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a specific number, the number of threads is limited by the JVM heap size. A pool of threads has a recommended number of threads equal to twice the number of cores that your computer has.

Answer (score 0):

No specific pre-defined number i guess, but in case of thread pool it's max integer value. Tried this code works on my local machine, so incase of threadpool max value will always be Integer.MAX_VALUE (per thread pool ofcourse).

```
 int threadCount=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
```