# Spring Boot run multiple Task concurrently

Tags: spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a question regarding Spring Boot. My web application has different Users. For each User, I need to run several Tasks (e.g import/export CSV, run rest request process it and answer it, ...). 
So let's say we have about 4 tasks per user. and now when I have 100 users I would have 400 tasks.
Now my question is how can I handle such an amount of task? The task should be scheduled with a cron expression and need to run parallel / concurrent so that no user has a disadvantage.

The Main Question is I really don't know how to make all this task run concurrently so that the tasks run parallel. How do I make that what SpringBoot-Things do I need to use (e.g a special Scheduler?).

Is it even possible to handle such amount of task running parallel/concurrently?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hello Nimal. It is not clear from this question what you expect from an answer. Please describe your situation in more detail, *where the problem is*, and what you have already tried. Also, how is spring boot related?

Comment: vaadin is probably unrelated as well, since it sounds like you want to execute tasks for each user in your db, and not for each user that has a Vaadin UI/Session open.

Comment: you havent addressed any of my mentioned points though. You seem to be in the information gathering phase. This is not the time to ask SO how to do it, but rather the time to research and learn using books, other online resources, etc. All this information is already out there. If you get stuck somewhere in the middle, we are happy to help you here with an explicit issue you have.

Comment: I'm new to Spring so a read that I could schedule tasks via cron, but I didn't understand if the task that I started can run concurrently. I haven't tried anything yet, because I wanted to now if this concurrent-scenario is possible, before I start implementing anything and put hours in it. So the first questions is:
Is it even possible to handle such amount of task running parallel/concurrently?

Comment: google says [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763579/how-many-threads-can-a-java-vm-support)