# Impact of heap space / non heap space memory on number of possible threads for a jvm process

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Based on a number of blog posts and stackoverflow questions I've come to the following conclusions:

- Maximum number of possible threads in a java application is dependent on the OS limit and NOT on stack size (xss). [Source](https://foojay.io/today/exploring-the-impact-of-stack-size-on-jvm-thread-creation-a-myth-debunked/)
- Also, according to the many answers to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763579/how-many-threads-can-a-java-vm-support) max possible threads can depend on a number of factors-

  - OS and CPU architecture
  - **Heap size**

I haven't considered the impact of heap size on the number of threads my application can create like the answers in the SO question suggest.

Is there a straightforward jvm property which allows me to configure the max memory that can be used for the creation of new threads? I don't think I can justify increasing -Xmx or any other memory section not explicitly dedicated to thread creation for increasing the number of threads in my app but I can't seem to find such a jvm property.

JVM in question is openjdk 8 (hotspot) 1.8.

Comment: Is the thread stack size not what you’re looking for?

Comment: As I understand it, thread stack size in java decides how many frames I can have for each Thread's stack / how deep I could get into recursive calls. What I want to configure is the number of threads my application can create irrespective of their stack size. This seems to be independent of stack size acc. to my first source.

Comment: Your first point is wrong, the maximum is dependent on the OS limit **and** stack size (or in other words, either you hit the OS limit on threads, or you run out of memory). In any case, as far as I know, Java does not have an option to limit this. To be honest, I'm not sure what you're doing that you need to worry about this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel by default, the stack memory is allocated but not committed. So if you only create threads but don’t run them or the code executed by the thread makes no use of the stack, the stack size does indeed not influence the number of threads you can create. It had an impact on 32 bit systems, of course, where even virtual memory (address space) was scarce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenJDK 8, there isn't a direct JVM property to configure the max. memory **specifically for thread creation**. The memory used for thread stacks is a part of the process's native memory, and the total native memory that a process can use is managed by the operating system.

So you were right about the `-Xmx` param – it controls the maximum heap size but doesn't influence the native memory that can be used for thread creation. The important note is that if your application uses less heap memory, *more native memory may be available for thread creation*, assuming the total memory of the system is fixed - perhaps that's something you may try.

So yeah, here isn't a direct JVM property to control the total memory used for thread creation specifically.

Comment: The flip side of this is that most threads will allocate memory to do whatever application-specific work they do. So the heap size also limits the number of threads in that way: the more concurrent threads are running, the more heap they will consume. The real-world limit on the number of threads you can run concurrently before it becomes detrimental depends on many interacting factors.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Does such a property exist for some JDK implementation other than Hotspot 1.8?